# When a user clicks a culture, an identifier for "culture" should be inserted / updated into the URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, routes, cultureinfo

I have a custom route setup in MVC4 which allows for a pattern like:

*culture/controller/action/id*

in addition to the default:

*controller/action/id*

I want to add a menu to my page that displays the available cultures.   When a user clicks a culture, an identifier for "culture" should be inserted / updated into the URL?

What is the BEST way to modify the route (url) like this in MVC4?

Answer (score 0):

Make an HtmlHelper

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CultureUrl(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string cultureName)
    {
        RequestContext requestContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext;

        RouteValueDictionary values = requestContext.RouteData.Values;

        var data = new
        {
            culture = cultureName ?? Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name,
            controller = values["controller"],
            action = values["action"],
            id = values["id"]
        };

        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
        string url =  urlHelper.RouteUrl(data);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(url);
    }
}
```

Then use it in the view:

```
<%foreach(var culture in Model.cultures){%>
    <%=Html.CultureUrl(culture)%>
<%}%>
```

Comment: I am not getting this to work?  On the line   culture = cultureName ?? Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name; the ; is underlined with an error of Synatax error, ',' expected.   I also see errors of The name 'controller' does not exist in the current context.   The name 'action does not exist in the current context, etc.

Comment: Semicolons fixed to commas

Comment: I swear I tried changing the semicolons to commas, but must be "Intellisense" was being a bit slow.   Anyway, not I get an error on string url = UrlHelper.RouteUrl(data); of "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.RouteUrl(object)'"

Comment: And when I try to reference it, I get "No Overload for Method 'CultureUrl' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: You need to have it in a static class. I have fixed the example accordingly.

Comment: Jani, thanks... when I try to call it from a model, I still am getting "No overload for method CultureUrl takes 1 arguments).   I get that the second argument is the culture name.  What would I use for the first argument?

Comment: See the example, use it in the view. The HtmlHelper is the first argument.